# Can't make UIUserNotificationActionBehaviorTextInput work

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, ios9

```
UIMutableUserNotificationAction *answer;
answer = [[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
[answer setActivationMode:UIUserNotificationActivationModeBackground];
[answer setTitle:@"Answer"];
[answer setIdentifier:@"Answer"];
[answer setDestructive:NO];
[answer setAuthenticationRequired:NO];
[answer setBehavior:UIUserNotificationActionBehaviorTextInput];

UIMutableUserNotificationCategory *actionCategory;
actionCategory = [[UIMutableUserNotificationCategory alloc] init];
[actionCategory setIdentifier:NotificationCategoryIdent];
[actionCategory setActions:@[answer]
                forContext:UIUserNotificationActionContextDefault];

NSSet *categories = [NSSet setWithObject:actionCategory];
UIUserNotificationType types = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|
                                UIUserNotificationTypeSound|
                                UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);

UIUserNotificationSettings *settings;
settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types
                                             categories:categories];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
```

This is how I set up my "Reply" action. As you can see, I specified the desired behavior. However, when I receive some notification, I pull it down and see this "Answer" button. What's the problem? Where is the textfield?

Comment: Why are you downvoting? There is a concrete question with provided code snippet. If you can't solve it, leave it. Or at least explain the reason. Do something meaningful.

Comment: The textfield would show up when you click the Answer button.